# OpenID Connect/Oauth2 - cache/use tokens

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect

I have a system with an REST API. The users of the REST API should be able to authenticate using OpenID Connect over Oauth2. The system itself has its own permission system. I need to map the IDPs user towards my local permission system. I'm thinking of saving the **openid** scope **sub** key in the local database as a unique user identifier.

But which token should I return to the user in the API. Should it be the oauth2 access id or token_id from the OpenID Connect layer, or perhaps both?

So I see these alternatives for the end-user of the API:

```
Authorization: Bearer <access_id>
```

```
Authorization: Bearer <token_id>
```

```
Authorization: Bearer <access_id>
TokenID: <token_id>
```

Without keeping the token_id/access_id in the system I need to get this from the client per API request. The token ID contains the JWT claims (sub) so I need this to validate what the client can do in my system.

Do I need to store any of the ID's below in my local database in order to validate API requests, or should the user provide it?

- Refresh token?
- Access token?
- Token ID?

I'm basically after authentication and user identification. I'm not after getting access to any external resources other than this.

And last question. Do I need to validate the access token every request towards the IDP or can I cache it? Do I need to validate both access token AND token id when using OpenID Connect?

**Edit:**

My system itself has an REST API and its own permission system. The permission system uses user IDs given by an any authentication system that uses OpenID Connect. The first user is manually added to the permission system.

Thought flow:

1. User of my system requests https://mysystem/login
2. User get redirected to https://idp/auth
3. IDP redirects successful login to https://mysystem/callback
   My system get user id (**sub**) and email from token id JWT.
4. And back to the user with a access token (not OIDC token id).
5. The user can now perform: curl -H "Authorization: bearer
   access token" https://mysytem/some/resource
6. Mysytem get this request from the user but don't know how to map access token to the user ID in the database w/o asking IDP for the user ID.

I want to use an external IDP to let users login, not to get access to resources from 3rd party systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

An access token DOES have a user id - see [step 14 of this write up](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow). Why do you think it doesn't?

The one exception to this rule is when there is no user involved - for app to app communication (eg client credentials flow). But you are not using that.

ORIGINAL ANSWER

You should just send the full access (bearer) token from UIs to APIs - and you should not need to store token details in your database.

When migrating to an OAuth architecture you will store user data in 2 places:

- Your normal product database - which often includes roles and user rights
- The Authorization Server - which generates a unique user id

It is fairly common to store the unique user id in product data for correlation and tracking, as you suggest. After login your APIs will often need to authorize based on product data.

A couple of my blog posts cover these topics in more detail:

- [User Data Management](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/02/user-data)
- [API Authorization and Claims Caching](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims)

My blog also links to [sample code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authorizer.ts) that ties these concepts together.

Comment: So I have my permission system combined with the user ID from IDP. But how can i map the access token (given in the bearer in the API requests) towards the user in my database?

Or do I need to lookup the /userinfo for each request to get the **sub** ID to map towards my database? I just don't get how I can map access token towards user in my database.

Comment: If you have existing users it is common to match up between OAuth data and Product data via email the very first time a login completes for the user. When I have migrated products I have done this, and made having a registered email a prerequisite for the migration.

Comment: I might be a bit unclear. I don't have an existing user. I want the user ID to come from Openid Connect over oauth2. Let's say some scenario like this:
1.) User requests /api/login towards my REST API
2.) I redirect to OpenID/Oauth2 endpoint for authentication
3.) I get back token ID / access ID. I get UID from token ID and perhaps email.
4.) I return access token to user as API response
5.) User request /api/some/resource with Bearer: <access token>
6.) My REST API receives the request to /api/some/resource with access token.
In the last step, 6. How can I map access token to the user?

Comment: Your API needs to do something like: 1. validate the token first. Then 2. read the token's unique user id (usually the 'sub' claim). Then 3. look up that user id in your API database's Users table. Then 4a. If found look up permissions for the user. If not found then 4b insert a new row into the User's table with default permissions. Then 5. Run API authorization to enforce permissions.

Comment: A more interesting question is how permissions are administered and by who. Perhaps an administrator needs to set these up in your API's database before the user's first login. If so then auto creating the user as above should not be allowed and your app should instead present an unauthorized error if the user in the token is not found. If you can explain how permissions are set up I can advise further. It is not just a technical question - you may need to design a secure onboarding process.

Comment: The "first user"/"admin" situation is a different topic I think, but very important indeed. I might still misunderstand, so bear with me. First request, the user login. My API server get token id + access token. I return <a token> (which token, access or token id?) to the user. For the users second request, what token should the user hand me, access id or token id? The second gives me the user id, the first will not. So if I map sub ID (from the token ID) in my database I know which user in my database the request is for (after validation of the token id). If I just get the access token....

Comment: ...I need to ask the IDP for who the access token is for, if I haven't saved the access token to the database for that user ID (**sub**). If I save the token ID + access token in my database then I can do whatever, but I feel it's a bad idea to save the tokens in the database for security reasons? Think of the situation as if the user was just using curl towards my rest API for everything.

Comment: You should only ever send the access token to the API, which will then validate it and extract the user id - see [step 14 of my write up](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow) for an example. In my case the unique user id is in the uid field. An id token is designed only for UIs and should never be sent to APIs. You should definitely NOT store tokens in a database.

Comment: But the access token from oauth2 is not containing anything related to user id? The token id from OpenID connect do contain user (**sub**) as unique identifier since it's an JWT. How can I get the user id from the access token you mean? Or  do you mean that I should request the user ID, based on the access token, from the IDP for every request?

Comment: To consolidate your understanding it might be worth spending a little time getting my [first tutorial code sample](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview) running on your PC - to see how it all fits together. Then adapt the sample to use your own IDP once it is working. Then apply knowledge learned to your real solution.

Comment: Can you edit your original post to explain how the client authenticates and gets tokens (which flow?). Then post the access token and id token bodies. Also post an example user id you'd like to get. Then I'll update my original answer.

Comment: The system is in the design phase, so I don't have any examples. I'm trying to understand how to implement things. I edited the original post with my thought flow.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. It really clears things up. I was under the impression that the access token was just a random token, hence they added OIDC id token that contained more info as JWT. But since the access token contains this information it really makes sense. Thanks!